# How do you efficiently select N 0-value pixels in an image to minimize the average distance between them?

Tags: algorithm, image, optimization

I have an image where each pixel has an associated binary value, either 0 or 1. My aim is to select N pixels of value 0 so as to minimize the average distance between these pixels. I'm looking for an efficient way to solve this problem.

I've considered using exhaustive search algorithms, but this quickly becomes inefficient when the number of pixels to be selected becomes large. So I'd like to know if there's a more efficient approach to solving this problem, perhaps using optimization techniques or specific algorithms.

I'm open to any suggestions and code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How do you define the average distance between N pixels?

Comment: When we have a set G made up of N pixels, the average distance between these pixels can be calculated by adding the distances between each pair of pixels in G, then dividing this sum by the total number of possible pairs.

The number of possible pairs is given by the formula N(N-1)/2. Consequently, the average distance between pixels in G can be calculated as follows:

d = (sum of distances between pixel pairs) / (N(N-1)/2)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) in disguise (it's slightly more complicated than it in fact), which is an [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problem. That means we (currently) do not have a way to solve the problem in less than O(2^n) time.

Basically, it is impossible to do this task perfectly in an efficient manner. I do suggest looking into [heuristic solutions](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/tsp-exact-solutions-vs-heuristic-vs-approximation-algorithms#2-heuristics-algorithms) of the problem.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for this enlightening information. I will try to apply a heuristic, although I initially thought this problem could be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: I'm contacting you again to ask if you could help me turn this problem into a variant of the travelling salesman's problem. I'd like to find the most efficient solution. The problem is that metaheuristics don't guarantee an exact solution, and I really need to solve this problem precisely. Thank you in advance for your help.